# Using networkx draw_networkx_labels with the keyword rotation='vertical' does not rotate label text

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, draw, networkx, label

I am using Networkx to draw a [Hierarchy Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3k6i.png).  I would like to rotate the labels to a vertical position, using the rotation keyword seems to have no effect.

```
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=lbl_pos, rotation='vertical')
```

Is it possible to draw the labels with a vertical rotation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you capture the output of `nx.draw_networkx_labels()` you can adjust all of the text parameters. For example,

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.path_graph(4)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, with_labels=False)
text = nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
for _, t in text.items():
    t.set_rotation('vertical')
```

[image]